# Append query result to another queryset

Tags: python, django, append, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
class A(models.Model)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, primary_key=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True,
                                  default=get_default_datetime)

class B(models.Model)
     user = models.CharField(max_length=25)
     email = models.CharField(max_length=25)
```

My goal is to create a list with username, email, last_login for all 'username' in model A that match to 'user' in model B. So it looks like this:

```
username    email      last login
user1       s@abc.com  2018-01-01 00:01:01
user2       t@cde.com  2017-12-30 05:01:00
...         ......     ...
```

and so on.

I did this in my view.py:

```
class userListView(ListView):
    template_name = 'user.html'
    context_object_name = 'user_list'

    def get_queryset(self):
        users = A.objects.values('username')
        for user in users:
           qs1 = A.objects.values('username', 'last_login')
           qs2 = B.objects.filter(user = user).values('user',  
                                                         'email')
           queryset = sorted(chain(qs1, qs2))
    return queryset
```

However, this does not work. I only get one entry. What am I doing wrong here?
I also tried to append qs2 to qs1. That did not work either.I was getting error that qs1 or qs2 has no attire of 'append'.

Comment: is there any relationship between A and B?

Comment: Can you explain this structure? Why do you have two separate models? Why don't you have a foreign key linking them?\

Comment: 'username' in A model and 'user' in model B are same. But B model includes more 'user' from anther group as well.